# Laravel not setting the provided foreignID

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I am currently trying to save a customer and using a hasMany Eloquent-Relationship to store addresses with it in a seperate table. Now i ran into the problem, that laravel is storing every value right in both tables except the foreignID. Here are some code snippets which I am using. The request returns to success, although the supplier_id (foreignKey) in the supplier_addresses table is not set.

Supplier Migration:

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('supplier_id')->primary();
    $table->string('supplierName');
    $table->string('taxNumber');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

SupplierAddresses Migration:

```
Schema::create('supplier_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('supplier_id');
    $table->string('street');
    $table->string('houseNumber');
    $table->string('stairway')->nullable();
    $table->string('floor')->nullable();
    $table->string('door')->nullable();
    $table->string('zipCode');
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Supplier Model:

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'supplier_id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = 'false';

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = [
        'supplier_id',
        'supplierName',
        'taxNumber'
    ];

    public function address() {
        return $this->hasMany(SupplierAddress::class, "supplier_id");
    }
}
```

SupplierAddresses Model:

```
class SupplierAddress extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'street',
        'houseNumber',
        'stairway',
        'floor',
        'door',
        'zipCode',
        'city',
        'type',
        'supplier_id'
    ];
}
```

Suppliers Controller:

```
class SuppliersController extends Controller
{
    public function show() {
        return view('addSupplier');
    }

    public function submit() {
        request()->validate([
            'supplier_id' => 'required',
            'supplierName' => 'required',
            'taxNumber' => 'required'
        ]);

        $supplier = Supplier::create([
            'supplier_id' => request('supplier_id'),
            'supplierName' => request('supplierName'),
            'taxNumber' => request('taxNumber')
        ]);
        $supplier->address()->create([
            'supplier_id' => request('supplier_id'),
            'street' => request('street'),
            'houseNumber' => request('houseNumber'),
            'stairway' => request('stairway'),
            'floor' => request('floor'),
            'door' => request('door'),
            'zipCode' => request('zipCode'),
            'city' => request('city'),
            'type' => 'P'
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Das Anlegen eines neuen Lieferanten war erfolgreich.');
    }
}
```

Suppliers Table:
[image: suppliers table]

SupplierAddresses Table:
[image: supplier_addresses table]

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign foreign key constrained between `suppliers` and `supplier_addresses` table

example

primary key

```
Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('supplier_id');
            $table->timestamps();
  });
```

foregin key

```
Schema::table('supplier_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id');
 
    $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
});
```

Or

```
Schema::table('supplier_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('supplier_id')->constrained('suppliers');
});
```

for more details you can see this `https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints`

Comment: I tried the second version now and it still results to supplier_id in supplier_addresses being 0. My problem here is that the supplier_id contains letters and cannot be an integer.

Comment: Did u change the ```data type``` of a column first?

Comment: yeah i did. and now i get a constraint violation, because laravel still tries to insert 0 into the supplier_id column in supplier_addresses, which isn't existing as a key in the suppliers table, because there the supplier_id gets set correctly.

Comment: supplier id is ```auto incremented``` right?

Comment: no. supplier_id is inserted from a form and processed to the controller via the request.

Comment: Or add ``` $table->id();``` in ```suppliers``` migration and migrate.

Comment: check the updated answer u will understand